# How to create a matrix in R where elements are dependent on column and row numbers?

Tags: r

In R, how can one elegantly create a 30 by 30 matrix where each element is 0.5 to the abs(i-j) power, where i and j are the column and row respectively?

I can do this using a loop but I wonder if there are more elegant ways.

Thanks

Comment: `outer` seems an option : `nm <- seq_len(5); outer(nm, nm, function(x, y) 0.5^(abs(x-y)))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a smaller matrix example for your desired output

```
N <- 5
(mat <- matrix(0.5, N, N))^abs(col(mat) - row(mat))
```

which gives

```
       [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 1.0000 0.500 0.25 0.125 0.0625
[2,] 0.5000 1.000 0.50 0.250 0.1250
[3,] 0.2500 0.500 1.00 0.500 0.2500
[4,] 0.1250 0.250 0.50 1.000 0.5000
[5,] 0.0625 0.125 0.25 0.500 1.0000
```